# Excel VBA 2016 Passing range cells to another sheet as calculated

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code to loop through a named range cells values if they are greater than 9 in sheet1. if the Cells value(>9) is found pass that cell value to sheet2 as calculated value

The format is like: `Sheet2.Range(name).Cells.value = Sheet1.Range(name).Cells.value`

Currently i managed to check those values in sheet1 and it works.

I am failing to assign the value in sheet2 cellTarget looping

**code:**

```
Dim rngSource As Range, cellSource As Range
Dim rngTagert As Range, cellTarget As Range

Set rngSource = Range("SourceRange") 'Sheet1
Set rngTagert = Range("TargetRange") 'Sheet2

For Each cellSource In rngSource
    If cellSource.Value >= 9 Then
        For Each cellTarget In rngTagert
            cellTarget.Value = cellSource.Value - 9
        Next cellTarget
    Else
        cellTarget.Value = cellTarget.Value
    End If
Next cellSource
```

Error says "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference"

Many Thanks

Comment: if you will try to indent your code properly, you'll find you have **One** `For Each cellSource In rngSource` and **Two** `Next cell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you

- either susbtitute

  first `Next cell` with `Next cellTarget`

  second `Next cell` with `Next cellSource`
- or just substitute each `Next cell` with `Next`

what follows is the second *option*:

```
Sub main()
    Dim rngSource As Range, cellSource As Range
    Dim rngTagert As Range, cellTarget As Range

    Set rngSource = Range("SourceRange") 'Sheet1
    Set rngTagert = Range("TargetRange") 'Sheet2

    For Each cellSource In rngSource
        If cellSource.value >= 9 Then
            For Each cellTarget In rngTagert
                cellTarget.value = cellSource.value - 9 'Sheet2 Cell.Value = Sheet1 Cell.Value -9
            Next
        Else
            cellSource.value = cellSource.value 'Sheet1 cellTarget.Value = cellTarget.Value 'Sheet2
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Oooh Ok. Thanks for that. I have rectified the mistake, but still i cannot assign the values to cellTarget on sheet2. Please take a closely look at my code where i assigned the cellTarget from cellSource using the loop if value is greater than 9.

Comment: without your data it's hard to tell. step through your code (press F8 to start macro and keep pressing it to jump to next statement to be executed) and querying relevant variables trough Immediate Window (e.g.: type `?cellSource.Address, cellSource.Value` and press return) to see what's going on. If you get stuck make a new post following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) rules. As to this post you may want to mark my answer as accepted since I solved its _Error says "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference"_ issue. Thank you

Comment: Thank you!!! Of-cause yes You have fixed that error... i will try to  rewrite the correct question. Thanks  for your Response

Comment: You are welcome. Since my answer solved your _original_ question you may then want to mark it as accepted. Thank you!